# Camel ftp2 quartz2 scheduler fires immediately after starting the route

Tags: apache, apache-camel, camel-ftp

Camel ftp2 when used with quartz2 cron scheduler fires immediately which is unexpected. Also it never closes the connection as there is no file to pickup.

How can I make it do the first polling only at the scheduled timing ?

route is generated by a program and so I cannot post it here but the from endpoint config is as below

```
sftp://192.168.7.10:22/***/?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&knownHostsFile=c%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5Cknown_hosts&move=.%2FARCHIVE%2F%24%7Bdate%3Anow%3AyyyyMMdd%7D%2F%24%7Bfile%3Aonlyname%7D&moveFailed=.%2FFailed&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F15+8-22+*+*+%3F&stepwise=false&username=*****
```

Comment: Can you post your Camel route code of how you configured the ftp2 endpoint, and tell us what Camel version you use

Comment: added details in content, I am using Camel 2.21.0

Comment: Quartz may think its mis-fired and start asap. At what time did you restart the app etc. Its likely some standard quartz behaivor. Try to read about its mis-fire and how that works. You can then potentially configure this in Camel with scheduler.xxx options

Comment: but why the connection was not closed at all. there was no file to process also.

Comment: Try changing logging level to DEBUG or TRACE and see what its logged in camel-ftp, to better understand what is going on. Your question and details here is too little for anyone to help very much